# C# ComboBox add and save items permanent after close and reload

Tags: c#

I have a question, so I have written `Add` event :

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //if (comboBox2.)
    { 
        comboBox2.Items.Add(comboBox2.Text);
    }
}
```

Then I tried to use Settings, and using System.Text.Json;
ComboBox2Items (Type:string, Scope:User)

```
private void SaveUserData()
{
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(comboBox2.Items);
    Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox2Items = json;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

then I made Closing event:

```
private void Form1_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    SaveUserData();
}
```

Why it does not save items, after reloading prog?(

Comment: it looks like it does save items.  What does the json variable have in it when you run it in the debugger?

Comment: Are you actually asking how to fill the combobox with what you have saved in the config as json when you restart the app? Your question is hard to read. Maybe you can phrase it better to be more clear.

Comment: @Ralf my question is, why items do not save after relaunching )

Comment: What they're saying is you've shown how you SAVE the data from the ComboBox to your settings, but you haven't shown how you are attempting to LOAD that data back into your ComboBox when the app restarts. This would likely be done in the `Load()` event of your form...

Comment: @Idle_Mind
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var cbData = Properties.Settings.Default.ComboBox2Items;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbData))
            {
                // Add some default values.
                comboBox2.Items.Add(comboBox2.Text);
                SaveUserData();
            }
            else
            {
                var itms = (object[])JsonSerializer.Deserialize(cbData, typeof(object[]));
                comboBox2.Items.AddRange(itms);
            }

        }

Comment: Edit your post above and add this latest code so we can see it formatted.